# Как сериализовать - десериализовать объекты с символами кириллицей?

Tags: java, spring, сериализация

Рест - сервис, манипулирующий сущностью User:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User implements Serializable {
    @XmlElement(name="Id")
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name = "Name", required = true)
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "Surname", required = true)
    private String surname;

    @XmlElement(name = "Age", required = true)
    private int age;

}
```

Мне требуется отправлять xml со значениями кириллицей в полях имя и фамилия.
При получении на бекенд - все хорошо.

Затем по логике я сериализую объект при помощи apache serialize и храню в базе.
По требованию, получая пользователя и десериализую, после десериализации получаю птичий язык в строковых полях. Как это можно исправить?

serialize(user) и deserialize(user)

использую org.springframework.util.SerializationUtils

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Можете расписать более подробно? А именно в каком формате у вас храниться в БД, как именно вы перед сохранением сериализируете и десеаризируете потом при выдаче. Также где именно проблема. Примеры кода добавьте с пометками, пож.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема возникала только при отправке запросов из интеграционных тестов.
Исчезла после донастройки restTemplate:

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
                .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Comment: А при чем тут Apache и SerializationUtils?

Comment: @Chubatiy вопрос с моей стороны был некорректным, поскольку не правильно определил рут-коз.